# How do I define a class that can only be instantiated via new (ie not on the stack)?

Tags: c++

I want to arrange things such that for a class Foo, this works:

```
Foo *f = new Foo()
```

but this does not (preferably a compile-time error):

```
Foo f;
```

Can this be done?

The specific reason is that Foo is actually a tracking class to make another heap-allocated object appear in a script environment. Foo's internals keeps a mapping from script references to C++ objects. The tracking object would be used like this:

```
Thing *t = new Thing();
(new FooThing(t))->PushToScriptStack();
```

If the tracking object is on the stack then the pointer becomes invalid at the end of scope, and I'm left with dangling pointers in my tracking data.

I have all this working well, I'm just looking for a little extra protection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the constructor private, have a create() which would allocate an instance of the object on the heap and return a pointer. You would have to handle deallocation yourself though.

For eg:

```
Foo *f = Foo::create();
```

and later:

```
Foo::destroy(f);
```

Comment: What about when you use it inside another object. Now it can only be represented by a pointer. Even if that object is on the heap.

Comment: Good point. Fortunately thats not something I need in this case.

Comment: @Robert Norris: I wood rather use Foo::destroy(f); to make sure an object is not deleting itself (as this can lead to problems).

Comment: @Martin - I agree. That was something that I overlooked; I'll edit my response to fix.

Answer (score 2):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but anyway...

This is covered in Item 27 in Scott Meyer's More Effective C++.

He says that you can do it by making the constructor private, but that might be somewhat troublesome because you have to make sure that all constructors are private. In addition to the possibility that you might add a new constructor and forget to make it private, you also have to think about compiler-generated constructors. Meyers reckons it's easier to just make the destructor private, because there can be only of of those, but of course that has its own implications.

If you don't already have it, I heartily recommend this book (and I suppose anything written by Meyers.)

Comment: In this case the alternate "constructor" and private destructor are appropriate. This class has a very specific purpose and is not intended to be subclassed. I do see your point though. Thanks for the recommendation; I have heard of this book but not read it yet. I'll go and track a copy down soon.